# Округление дробных чисел до целых

Tags: java

Какие существуют в Java стандартные средства для округления чисел?

- Пример округления: 3.49 - 3, 3.50 - 4, 3.51 - 4.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

1. `Math.ceil(n)` — возвращает наименьшее целое число, которое больше или равно
   аргумента n.
2. `Math.floor(n)` — возвращает наибольшее целое число,
   которое меньше или равно аргументу n.
3. `Math.round(n)` — возвращает
   целое число, ближайшее к аргументу n (округляет n).

Пример с `ceil`:

```
int result = (int)Math.ceil(3.8);   
System.out.println(result);            //4

int result = (int)Math.ceil(3.3);
System.out.println(result);            //4
```

Пример с `floor`:

```
int result = (int)Math.floor(3.8);   
System.out.println(result);            //3

int result = (int)Math.floor(3.3);
System.out.println(result);            //3
```

Пример с `round`:

```
int result = (int)Math.round(3.8);   
System.out.println(result);            //4

int result = (int)Math.round(3.3);
System.out.println(result);            //3
```

Comment: _"которое больше аргумента n"_ - больше или равно же?

Comment: @Qwertiy, да, верно, исправил :)

Answer (score 6):

В годы моей юности, когда не было таких умных методов `round/ceil/floor`, округление делали примерно так:

```
double x=8.3;
int i;
i=(int )(x+0.5); //round
i=(int )(x); //floor
i=(int )(x+1); //ceil
```

Comment: Эм.. Но `x+1` неверно же, если число было целое...

Comment: Да, правда :) единственное оправдание, что в те времена народ не сильно озабачивался функцией `ceil`

Comment: А ещё для отрицательных не работает, похоже.

Comment: @Qwertiy какой же вы право, нудный :)

Comment: Ну плюс-то поставил, можно и понудеть ;)

Answer (score 1):

Метод `Math.round()` в Java возвращает `long` или `int` (целое число), ближайшее к вещественному числу, `double` или `float`, аргумента. Иными словами - осуществляет округление до целых чисел.

```
double d1 = 1.49;
double d2 = 1.50;

Math.round(d1);
Math.round(d2);
```

И результат:

```
d1 = 1
d2 = 2
```

Answer (score 0):

вот правильный код:

```
double b=6.7;
float c=4.5f;
double h=4.1;
System.out.println(Math.round(h));//вывод на экран ЦЕЛОЧИСЛЕННОЕ значение типа int к блажайшему числу(4.5 будет иметь число 5)
System.out.println(Math.floor(c));/*округляет число типа float вниз до ближайшего в тип double*/
System.out.print(Math.ceil(h));//округляет число типа double вверх в тип double
```

Comment: А что, у остальных тут код неправильный?