# Как окрулить число в HTML?

Tags: javascript, html, thymeleaf

Как округлить число в HTML до заданного количества знаков после запятой, если я использую значения из java-коллекции с помощью thymeleaf?

Кусок таблицы выглядит так:

```html
<tr>
  <td>Коэффициент детерминации</td>
  <td th:text="${forecastResult.getModelSpecifications().get('sumSqResiduals')}"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>Средняя ошибка аппроксимации</td>
  <td th:text="${forecastResult.getModelSpecifications().get('sigma')}"></td>
</tr>
```

Вот что в итоге:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: никак, округляй в java

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Html - язык разметки страниц, следовательно он не умеет работать с числами, он определяет как они будут расположены на страницы.

Вам нужно округлить в java или воспользоваться jscript(он присутствует почти во всех современных бразурах)

Comment: Спасибо. А можете примерно подсказать, как использовать здесь js, для того чтобы округлить значение?
Ну то есть понятно, что должен быть какой-то скрипт, но как он выглядит не пойму, ведь у меня thymeleafe, который дико меня путает.

Comment: Тебе не проще в java округлить числа? 
https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/457867/%D0%9E%D0%BA%D1%80%D1%83%D0%B3%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%B4%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85-%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%B5%D0%BB-%D0%B4%D0%BE-%D1%86%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8B%D1%85

Comment: не, так как эти значения много где используются еще, а у меня вопрос только отображения.