# Конвертация double в int

Tags: java

Доброго времени суток. 
Есть код, который проводит некоторые операции с числами типа double а потом выводит их на экран. Есть ли возможность вывести целые числа (1.0, 2.0, 3.0 и т.д) без нолей?

Comment: Double.intValue()

Comment: разве обычный каст `(int)` не сработает?

Comment: @Sviat Volkov `intValue()` - это метод объекта, так что так не получится : `Double.intValue()`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

ТС спрашивал не о приведении типов, а о:

> Есть ли возможность вывести целые числа (1.0, 2.0, 3.0 и т.д) без нолей?

Надо просто форматировать вывод:

```
double d=2.0;
NumberFormat formatter = new DecimalFormat("#0");     
System.out.println(formatter.format(d));
```

Приведение к `int`, просто приведет к переполнению, потому что максимальное значение `int` равно `2^31-1=2147483647`, а максимальное значение `double` равно `1.7*10^308`

Answer (score 3):

Как вариант выводить их с помощью приведения к int, как Вам подсказали уже в коментариях:

```
System.out.print((int) 2.5);
System.out.print((int) doubleValue);
```

или же использовать округление (зависит от Вашей задачи)

```
Math.ceil(n) — возвращает наименьшее целое число, которое больше или равно аргумента n.
Math.floor(n) — возвращает наибольшее целое число, которое меньше или равно аргументу n.
Math.round(n) — возвращает целое число, ближайшее к аргументу n (округляет n).
```

Вот [тут](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/457867/%D0%9E%D0%BA%D1%80%D1%83%D0%B3%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%B4%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85-%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%B5%D0%BB-%D0%B4%D0%BE-%D1%86%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8B%D1%85) уже отвечали про округление.

Answer (score 1):

Используйте метод объекта `intValue()` если у вас тип `Double`. Если примитив, то явное приведение - `(int)doubleVar`

Comment: Вредно, поскольку может вызвать переполнение `int`